# Books on string algorithms

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

There have been numerous posts on string algorithms:

- [Algorithm to find articles with similar text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246961/algorithm-to-find-similar-text),
- [Similar String algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451884/similar-string-algorithm),
- [Efficient string matching algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613133/efficient-string-matching-algorithm)

However, no general literature was mentioned.

Could anyone recommend a book(s) that would thoroughly explore various string algorithms?
The topic which is of special interest is approximate string matching [things like google-offered corrected search string variants :) ].

Thanks a lot for advice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised no-one has mentioned Dan Gusfield's excellent book [Algorithms on Strings, Trees and Sequences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521585198) which covers string algorithms in more detail than anyone would probably need.  It served me very well for a project on protein sequencing that I was working on a few years ago.  After reading this book you will learn:

- Naive String Matching
- Preprocessor Based algorithms (Boyer Moore, Knuth-Morris-Pratt)
- Regex matching algorithms
- Karp-Rabin and similar methods
- Suffix tree methods (Ukkonen's method, etc)
- Sequence alignment (Levenshtein distance and string similarity, and multiple sequence alignment)
- Applications to DNA sequencing, gene prediction and other areas.

Comment: +1 It's called "Algorithms on Strings Trees and Sequences" and is an awesome reference

Comment: And it's "relatively" new (compared to other text mentioned in other answers), because it incorporated many recent academic works.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a book recommendation, but this library and site is a library that offers plenty of efficient string matching algorithm implementations:

http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html

It also provides links to further learning for each and where each is best applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one. It seems to contain whole bunch of terms and consice introductory to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

[Jewels of Stringology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9810248970)

Answer (score 1):

[CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) has some string processing algorithms, but it's not specific to them.

Including:

- [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
- [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm)
- matching by finite automata
- edit distance

Answer (score 1):

[TRE](http://laurikari.net/tre/) is an open-source library that implements approximate matching. The [About page](http://laurikari.net/tre/about/) has some interesting hints about how it works, although I'm not sure it provides the sort of in-depth analysis you're looking for. The source code is probably more enlightening from that perspective.