# Looking for API similar to Spell checker

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I have a list of words in a text file. What I want is for an input word a list of words that are similar to the input word. So the program should work similar to a spell checker API with only thing that the dictionary is limited to my list of words.

I can write my own code if I get some pointers to Spell Checker algorithm or regular expressions.

Comment: You may find this question has some useful tips to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346757/how-do-spell-checkers-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).  The Levenshtein algorithm gives the "edit distance" between two words, that is, how similar they are.  Their implementation is quite fast - I tested it against another implementation I found online and it was about 1/3 faster if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. With some googling I could find the source for StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance. And it did the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please accept the answer you found most helpful by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend taking a look at [Peter Norvig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig)'s article on [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). It's worth reading. And it doesn't involve too much of a complexity. If you scroll down the page, you can see links to Java implementations. Then, you can customize it to your own needs.

Comment: I looked at couple of Java implementations mentioned at the botom of the page. I tried one of them and it was a bit slow with long strings. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance